# How to update character set of a excel sheet through Java

Tags: java, performance, swing, excel, jakarta-ee

I am extracting Russian characters from db and generating one excel sheet. But unfortunately in extracted excel sheet, I have to change the character set manually to "UNICODE(UTF-8)" , otherwise I can't able to see Russian character. Is anybody aware how to update this character set through java(I am not asking to convert the value) ?

Let me know if anything needs to be provided from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Apache POI` an option ?
Apache POI manages the encoding for you. All the text returned is in Java Unicode format (which I believe is UTF-16, and not UTF-8)

Here is how you read Excel sheet in POI:

```
try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    //Get first sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
    FileOutputStream out =
        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Source: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/